# Bounded 2nd derivative and finding a bound for the 1st derivative

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f:[0,1]\xrightarrow{}\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ the $f''$ exists and it's continuos on $[0,1]$, suppose that $|f''(x)|\leq A$ for all $x\in [0,1]$. Show that $|f'(x)|\leq A/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $|f'(1/2)| \leq A/4$.

I tried using the Taylor's theorem with Lagrange remainder by plugging 0 and 1 in order to make some terms vanish, however I wasn't able to isolate $A$ and $f'(x)$.
$$
f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0) + \frac{1}{2!}f'(c)(x-x_0)^2 \\
f(x) = f(0)   + f'(0)x + \frac{1}{2!}f'(c)x^2
f(1/2) = f(0)   + \frac{f'(0)}{2} + \frac{1}{2! 4}f''(c) = \frac{f'(0)}{2} + \frac{1}{2! 4}f''(c)\\
\leq \frac{f'(0)}{2} + \frac{1}{2! 4}A = \frac{1}{2}\left(f'(0)+\frac{1}{4}A \right)
$$
I also thought of applying Rolle's theorem in some way, but I don't think it fits anywhere.
If someone could point me in a useful direction, I would be glad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track: Let $x_0\in[0,1]$. Then $$f(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac 12 f''(c)(x - x_0)^2$$ for $c$ between $x$ and $x_0$. Since $f(x) = 0$ for $x=0$ and $x=1$, it holds that $$0 = f(0) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(0 - x_0) + \frac 12 f''(c_1)(0 - x_0)^2$$
and $$0 = f(1) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(1 - x_0) + \frac 12 f''(c_2)(1 - x_0)^2.$$
Thus, both equations yield $$\begin{align*}f'(x_0) &= \frac 12 f''(c_1){x_0}^2 - \frac 12 f''(c_2)(1 - x_0)^2 \end{align*}$$
and therefore $$\begin{align*} \vert f'(x_0)\vert &= \left\vert \frac 12 f''(c_1){x_0}^2 - \frac 12 f''(c_2)(1-x_0)^2\right\vert \\ &\leq \frac 12 A\big({x_0}^2 + (1-x_0)^2\big) \\ &\leq \frac 12 A\end{align*}$$ using the triangle inequality, the condition $\vert f''(x)\vert\leq A$, and $x_0\leq 1$. Note that if $x_0 = \frac 12$, the other result $\vert f'(1/2)\vert \leq \frac 14 A$ is obtained.

Comment: In the beginning you said "for $c$ between $x$ and $x_0$". What's the form of that inequality? Is it $x \leq c \leq x_0$? It's not clear to me.

Comment: well it depends on what $x$ and what $x_0$ is. I $x_0\leq x$ then $x_0\leq c\leq x$. Conversely, if $x\leq x_0$ the inequality you have stated applies. It follows from the mean value theorem applied to the remainder of a Taylor approximation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)

Comment: an alternative formulation would be that $c = \lambda x_0 + (1-\lambda) x$ for some $0\leq\lambda\leq 1$.

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, you said that if $x_0 = 1/2$ then the result $|f'(1/2)| \leq 1/4$ follows, but I didn't obtain it. Could you should how? I got $\frac{A}{2} \times \frac{13}{16} > \frac{A}{4}$ since $13/16>1/2$ .

Comment: Oh you're right, I had written $1/4 + (3/4)^2$ by lack of attention. Probably too tired.

Comment: I made a mistake in a comment I just deleted. For $x_0 = 1/2$ the term in parentheses is already equal to $1/2$ and the result follows :-)